# Intent extras in Unit test Android Mockito

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-intent, mockito, extras

I am trying to verify that specific extras are added to Intent, but all the time I get null for the Intent in Unit test Android. I have the following class that need to be test:

```
public class TestClass extends SomeNotifier {
        private Intent mIntent = new Intent("testintent");

        public TestClassConstructor(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        @Override
        public void notifyChange() {
            mIntent.putExtra("Key one", 22);
            mIntent.putExtra("Key two", 23);
            mIntent.putExtra("Key three", 24);
            getContext().sendBroadcast(mIntent);
        }
    }
```

And the test is the following (I tried with mockIntent as well, but the result is the same, again the extras are null):

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class TestClassTest {

  @Mock
  Context mMockContext;

  @Test
  public void sendBroadcastTest() {

  ArgumentCaptor<Intent> argument = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Intent.class);

  TestClass testClassNotifier = new TestClass (mMockContext);
  testClassNotifier.notifyChange();
  verify(mMockContext).sendBroadcast(argument.capture());


 Intent intent = argument.getValue();
 //THE INTENT IS NULL
 Assert.assertTrue(intent.hasExtra("Key one"));

    }
}
```

Do you have any suggestion how should I make this test to work?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Since you are trying to test and make assertions about an `Intent` object that is part of the Android framework and not just using it as a dependency, where you could simply mock it,  vanilla unit tests won't work because the Android framework objects are simply 'empty' test double in unit tests.

This unit test + Android framework objects' limitation is [explained better here](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/local-tests#mockable-library).

You can achieve what you want by using a library such as [Robolectric](https://robolectric.org/writing-a-test/), that enable testing Android framework classes without using an emulator or device. The documentation has an example of assertions with an `Intent` instance that can guide you to do what you want :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Mockk for mocking `intent`

```
 @Test
fun `Test`() {
    // Arrange
    val longValue = 1000L
    val enumValue = ModelEnum.MODEL1
    val intentMock = spyk<Intent>()
    every { intentMock.extras?.getLong("KEY_LONG_VALUE") } returns longValue
    every { intentMock.hasExtra(CheckoutRouter.RESULT_PAYMENT_TYPE) } returns true
    every { intentMock.getSerializableExtra("KEY_ENUM_VALUE") } returns enumValue

    // Action
    val a = A(intent = intentMock)
    val longValueResult = a.getLongValue()
    val enumValueResult =  a.getEnumValue()

    // Assert
    Assert.assertEquals(longValue, longValueResult)
    Assert.assertEquals(enumValue, enumValueResult)
}

class A (val intent: Intent){

    fun getLongValue():Long? {
        return intent.extras?.getLong("KEY_LONG_VALUE")
    }

    fun getEnumValue():ModelEnum? {
        return intent.getSerializableExtra("KEY_ENUM_VALUE") as? ModelEnum
    }
}

enum class ModelEnum{
    MODEL1,MODEL2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write unit test for `processIntentExtras` using `Mockito` and `JUnit`:

```
        @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
        class MyActivityTest {

            @Mock
            private lateinit var intent: Intent

            private lateinit var myActivity: MyActivity

            @Before
            fun setup() {
                MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
                myActivity = MyActivity()
            }

            @Test
            fun testProcessIntentExtras() {
                // Prepare the mock intent with extras
                `when`(intent.getIntExtra("my_key", 0)).thenReturn(42)

                // Call the method to be tested
                myActivity.processIntentExtras(intent)

                // Add your assertions here to verify the processing logic
            }
        }
```