# Kotlin - Why is this variable null after initialization?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to write a unit test for some Android code that looks for a specific key being present in an `Intent` object. As part of my test, I'm creating an `Intent` object and adding a String to it. However, when I use the below code, my variable is initalized to null:

```
val data = Intent().putExtra("key", "value")
// data is null
```

If I split this up into two lines, it works just fine:

```
val data = Intent()
data.putExtra("key", "value")
// data is non-null and contains my key/value
```

What feature of the Kotlin language is causing this to happen?

---

Note that `putExtra()` returns an `Intent` object. From the Android source:

```
public @NonNull Intent putExtra(String name, String value) {
    if (mExtras == null) {
        mExtras = new Bundle();
    }
    mExtras.putString(name, value);
    return this;
}
```

In the first case, the inferred type is `Intent!`. I was under the impression that this just means that it's an `Intent` or an `Intent?` but Kotlin doesn't want to make devs go crazy with Java platform types. Still, given that `putExtra()` returns a non-null value, I'd expect the actual value of `data` to be non-null.

Comment: How do you know it's null? Does it cause a crash?

Comment: And, do you literally mean "unit test" (`app/src/test/`) and not "instrumented test" (`app/src/androidTest/`)?

Comment: @TheWanderer I know it is null due to both stepping through the code in the debugger and due to an NPE in my code under test

Comment: @CommonsWare it is in the `test/` directory, not `androidTest/`, but if I use the two-line approach the test runs successfully and passes.

Comment: Unit tests run on the JVM. There is no `Intent` class in the JDK. So, you are getting your `Intent` class from someplace else (e.g., Mockito). The rules of what `putExtra()` returns might be different for the mock than it is for the real `Intent` class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Intent extras in Unit test Android Mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46469049/intent-extras-in-unit-test-android-mockito)

Comment: The question isn't exactly the same, but it looks like @CommonsWare has the right idea: if you do a unit test with Android classes, methods are no-op and any that have an Object return will return null.

Comment: Yep, that sounds totally plausible. Testing now...

Comment: Confirmed. Thanks very much for the help, all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is what @CommonsWare and @TheWanderer mentioned in comments: my test class was in the `test/` directory, so it was using a mock `Intent` implementation instead of the real thing.

When I move my test to the `androidTest/` directory, everything works as expected. The observed behavior has nothing to do with Kotlin.

---

Some extra info about why this was so confusing...

First, I was mistaken when I wrote this:

> ```
> val data = Intent()
> data.putExtra("key", "value")
> // data is non-null and contains my key/value
> ```

The `data` variable *was* non-null, but it did not actually contain my key/value pair. The mock `Intent` implementation I was using was dropping the `putExtra()` call.

So, why was my test passing?

The one particular test I decided to dig deeper on was testing the negative case (when a key other than the one it expects is present in the `Intent`). But I wasn't passing an Intent with the wrong key, I was passing an Intent with no keys at all. Either way, though, the expected key is not present, and the method returns `false`.

The positive case (where the required key actually *was* passed to `putExtra()`) failed with an `AssertionError`. Too bad I didn't pick this one to scrutinze.

My main project has apparently stubbed `Intent.putExtra()` as a no-op, via the `returnDefaultValues = true` gradle option. When I create a new project and try to reproduce this issue, I get a very clear error:

> ```
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Method putExtra in android.content.Intent not mocked. See http://g.co/androidstudio/not-mocked for details.
>     at android.content.Intent.putExtra(Intent.java)
>     at com.example.stackoverflow.IntentTest.test(IntentTest.kt:12)
> ```

Unfortunately, with the mocked `putExtra()`, I never got this helpful message.